# Windows 8 & ClickOnce

Tags: .net, windows-8, clickonce, internet-explorer-10

I have a ClickOnce App that is published to a URL and run wells on Windows XP. I have just install Windows 8 with IE 10 and am having a little problem.

In IE, the `.application` (Manifest) file is being downloaded and displayed in the View Downloads Form and it says, `“do you want to open this file”`, then I need to click on the Open button in the `Downloads Form`, for the application to open. In XP, the application is opened automatically and the View Downloads form is not shown.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare IE7 on XP versus IE10 on Windows 8. They are two different browsers running on different operating systems. There are new behaviours in IE10 and you cannot change how browsers work by default.

If you try in another browser (other than IE) you will have another behaviour, you cannot handle this if you try to perform an action from an untrusted machine.

However if users of your application are in your company (same domain) you may be able to change their browser behaviours/security with GPOs.

**UPDATE:**

If you are in a big company it is difficult to change GPOs or security settings, ask to your network administrator if you can.

Alternatively another solution could be to bypass the browser download, in other you create a batch that will automatically start the installer without using the browser (and then bypassing the IE process). You can put this batch on the network. Obviously it depends how do you want your users instal the application.

Comment: All clients are trusted and they all access the application via an Intranet. How do i change their browser behaviors/security with GPOs??

Comment: It depends what is your system. Are you allowed to change those settings in your company? You can have a look at [GPOs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274846). I have updated my answer.

Comment: try your application install with setup.exe link. and check what is happening.?